# Is there research to support the idea that social networking sites could be improved to "feel more" in order to avoid "online disinhibition effect"?

Tags: social-psychology, social-networks

Is there research to support the idea that social networking sites could be improved to "feel more" in order to avoid "online disinhibition effect"?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_disinhibition_effect

That is, having e.g. videos instead of static pictures of people? In order to emphasize that they're real?

Comment: I once supervised a master student's project in which he tried to add unrelated background bio in context of debates on Reddit. He did a user study with initial positive results as far as I recall. I could try to find his thesis again and redirect you to it; he _should_ have relevant related work in his background section. :)

Comment: @StevenJeuris Yes that's a good addition. I've noticed that having people carry "rep tags" does add to a quality of behavior. It feels easier to downplay low rep people than high rep. But which then intuitively leads to improved behavior as rep increases.

Comment: This is the thesis mentioned by Steven Jeuris (I'm the author): https://github.com/simongray/StatementAnnotator/raw/master/Thesis_final_no_appendix_fixed.pdf I don't have enough points to comment apparently since I just created this account. It's just a Master's thesis and a bit programming heavy, but feel free to ask questions if you want.